# ##[error]System error 1326 has occurred. - VSTS Release Task: Windows Machine File Copy

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, system-error

I am using VSTS to deploy an MVC Website and a database to an Azure Virtual Machine . While trying to copy the needed dacpac file i get this error: ##[error]System error 1326 has occurred.

---

Here is the log from the release:

```
2017-11-03T10:29:50.7943998Z ##[section]Starting: Copy files from *******
2017-11-03T10:29:50.8436980Z ==============================================================================
2017-11-03T10:29:50.8436980Z Task         : Windows Machine File Copy
2017-11-03T10:29:50.8436980Z Description  : Copy files to remote machine(s)
2017-11-03T10:29:50.8436980Z Version      : 2.0.1
2017-11-03T10:29:50.8436980Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2017-11-03T10:29:50.8436980Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=627415)
2017-11-03T10:29:50.8436980Z ==============================================================================
2017-11-03T10:29:54.1838780Z Copy started for - *******
2017-11-03T10:29:54.9182580Z ##[error]System error 1326 has occurred.

2017-11-03T10:29:54.9807578Z ##[section]Finishing: Copy files from *******
```

---

The error does not give me alot of details about the problem so i started digging deeper in the problem. I have Enabled all the needed ports, checked if the account specified was an administrator(it was), made sure the date was set correctrly(tried this because there are some examples where it works).

Azure File Copy does not help me in my situation.

Any information would be very appreciated. Thank you !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for my situation, i hope this helps someone.

Answer:

At first, in my release definition, i was running the Windows Machine Copy task on a deployment group phase. This was the problem. After a while i made another phase that runs on the Agent, this turned out to be the fix. It works with HOSTEDVS2017 Agent, and on a private Agent aswell.

Good luck !!!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem also. I solved it by changing the version of the script from 2* to 1*. I think the problem has to do with the password
look these links
[enter link description here](http://blog.halkoutsa.co.uk/2016/03/21/vsts-release-management-and-system-error-1326/)

[enter link description here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f76fbb32-1dde-4787-9a8c-3bd3e0feb7af/windows-file-copy-task-fails-system-error-1326-has-occurred-the-user-name-or-password-is?forum=tfsbuild)

Comment: Your first link is dead.

Answer (score 0):

Solved
Switching to version 2* I starting getting error 1326 with the same parameters that work for version 1*.

Turns out error 1326 is credential error. I was passing the "username" and "password" for Admin user on the remote server, but version 2* of Windows Machine File Copy now requires "domain\username" and "password" to work.